# Laravel 8 form to update database

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms

I am creating a simple blog site with CRUD functionality in Laravel 8. I have done this before using the deprecated Laravel forms, but am now trying to do it using HTML forms.

However, I am having some problem with the update part of the website. I have a controller called BlogsController with this function to be called to update the blog in the database which should be called when the user submits the form to update.

 **BlogsController update function**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'category' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',    
            'read_time' => 'required'        
        ]);

        $blog = Blog::find($id);        
        $blog->title = $request->input('title');        
        $blog->body = $request->input('body'); 
        $blog->category = $request->input('category');
        $blog->description = $request->input('description');
        $blog->read_time = $request->input('read_time');     
        $blog->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $blog->save();

        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Blog Updated');
    }
```

What action does the form need to direct to? 
**Top of update form**

```
<form method="POST" action="update">
```

**Route in web.php**

```
Route::resource('blog', 'App\Http\Controllers\BlogsController');
```

**Implementation in Laravel forms**

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['App\Http\Controllers\BlogsController@update', $blog->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

Comment: This library was removed from the core and taken on by the laravel collective: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.x/html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a list of all your application routes and names by running

```sh
$ php artisan route:list
```

For your blog update route you should use

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('blog.update', ['blog' => $blog]) }}">
  @method('PATCH')
</form>
```

in your template.

Make sure you have you have your [`csrf`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#preventing-csrf-requests) token set correctly at your form by using the `@csrf`, see Laravel docs.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I am trying to do something similar for delete now, but for some reason I am just getting redirected to the show post rather than deleting it. Any idea what I have done wrong?
`<form method="DELETE" action="{{ route('blog.destroy', ['blog' => $blog]) }}">                                                                                              
                                                <input type="submit" value="Delete">      
                                            </form>`

Comment: For delete use the same syntax: `method="post"` and `@method('DELETE')`.

Comment: @ThomasRead you should add the csrf token ... the Form builder would add this for you when you opened a form

Answer (score 1):

One thing that's cool with Laravel is [Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding). So what's that mean? We can do something like this in your `update` method

```
// BlogController.php

public function update(Request $request, Blog $blog) {
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
        'category' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',    
        'read_time' => 'required' 
    ]);

    $blog->title = $request->title;
    $blog->body = $request->body;
    $blog->category = $request->category;
    $blog->description = $request->description;
    $blog->read_time = $request->read_time;

    if ($blog->save()) {
        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Blog Updated');
    } else {
        // handle error.
    }
}
```

In your template, you'll want to make sure you're using a `PATCH` method:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('blog.update', ['blog' => $blog]) }}">
    @csrf
    @method('PATCH')
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check all route list:

```
        $ php artisan route:list
```

your route should be like:

```
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('blog.update', ['blog' => $blog]) }}">              
           {{csrf_field()}}
           {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Resource route for your CRUD functionality. In that case, Update method in resource controller called via PUT method and not POST. So, in your form, just add this to change the Form submission method to PUT:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```

Also, in your form declaration, you have to add the destination route like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('blog.update', $blog->id) }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have the option of using the `action` to get a URL to the registered route:

```
action('App\Http\Controllers\BlogsController@update', ['blog' => $blog])
```